# iOS-charts invert the X axis direction

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I have a bar chart built using [Daniel Gindi iOS-charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts). It represents history data over a period of time.  The issue I am having is that the data is being plotted from left-to-right (new data -> old data).  I need it to be plotted as right-to-left (old data -> new data).  I know that I can reverse the order I input data into `BarChartData`, but then I have the issue of the chart still being left aligned.  It needs to be right aligned.  I found a discussion [here](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/738) talking about the issue of inverting the x-axis and how it could be resolved (currently not an included feature of the framework), however I can't figure out what actually needs to be done.  Here are examples of what I need:

This is what my chart currently looks like:

[image]

This is what I needs it to look like:

[image]

**My Questions**

Is there a way to invert the x-axis?

*or*

Is there a way to right align the chart?

*Here is some of my code and attempts to resolve the issue:*

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var barChartView: BarChartView!

    //...

    func plotChart() {

        // Create history data
        //...

        barChartView.data = chartData  // 'chartData' is the BarChartData() containing all of the history information

        // No efect
        barChartView.legend.direction = .RightToLeft

        // Chart breaks
        barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinValue = 30
        barChartView.leftAxis.axisMaxValue = 0

        // Breaks the ability to zoom
        barChartView.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(CGFloat(40))
        barChartView.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(CGFloat(1))

    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried to change `barChartView.legend.direction = .LeftToRight` ?

Comment: Yes I have.  It doesn't seem that `.LeftToRight` or `. RightToLeft ` are doing anything.

Comment: have you read my answer?

Comment: You can config your data source from new to old and use only right x axis it would also work

Comment: @AshishThakkar I'm looking into it now.  I don't like tampering with the source files, but I'll give it a try.  Do you know if it will effect all charts that are created?

Comment: obviously it will effected to all chart

Comment: That could be an issue. I have multiple charts, and only one needs this re-alignment.

Comment: Okay I am trying to search for same. you also do R&D and if you found anything then post here your answer

Answer (score 0):

In the `chartLegend.swift` file there is a variable:

`public var direction = ChartLegendDirection.LeftToRight`

Try to make the change in that file, it might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This library doesn't support right to left alignment directly.

Refer - https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/738

You have to implement something on library level to make it trick right to left alignment.

**Edited answer**

After working some around, i found the solution, hope this will help you out.

[Download sample code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ooURy3zGWKN1g4QVJxb2YzdEk/view?usp=sharing)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


  @IBOutlet weak var barChartView: BarChartView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let months = ["7/23/2016", "7/22/2016", "7/21/2016", "7/20/2016", "7/19/2016", "7/18/2016", "7/17/2016"]
        let unitsSold = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 50.0, 30.0]

        setChart(months, values: unitsSold)

    }


    func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

        var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

        for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
            if !values[i].isZero {
                let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
                dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
            }
        }

        let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "")
        let chartData = BarChartData(xVals: dataPoints, dataSet: chartDataSet)
        barChartView.data = chartData

        barChartView.leftAxis.enabled = false
        barChartView.descriptionText = ""
        barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .Bottom

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
                dataEntries.append(dataEntry) is removed in latest update pod.

Answer (score -1):

Ios charts to support Right to left alignment

Steps:

- enable right axis & disable left axis
- invert the data
- set yaxis dependency while drawing Yaxis `chartView.getAxis(YAxis.AxisDependency.right)`
- set axis dependency for barChartDataSet as `YAxis.AxisDependency.right`

You are done

Happy Reading

Comment: Please share proper details along with the code snippet.